# Why are my makefile errors in gibberish?

Tags: windows, character-encoding, makefile, g++

When compiling C++ code (on Windows XP, in the cmd), the makefile gives this error:

```
make: *** Σ·ΘΘ≡ß∞ φΘ∞∞δ ∩Θα Ωα ,`\Program' ·∙°σπ `g++' Σ°Φε.  Stop.
```

How should I turn this into readable text?
Thanks.

Comment: I'll let the Greeks know that their alphabet is illegible :)

Comment: Without seeing the makefile, it will be relatively difficult to help you. It'd also be nice to have the full output from running `make`.

Comment: Probably you are actually working in APL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message is in Hebrew in [ISO-8859-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-8) encoding, but the command prompt emulator interprets it as [Codepage 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or something similar.

This is the same error decoded:

```
make: *** התיינבל םיללכ ןיא ךא ,`\Program' תשרוד `g++' הרטמ.  Stop.
```

Note that the text is backwards: ISO-8859-8 stores Hebrew text in "visual order", so from left to right, for sake of easier rendering, but the browser renders it from right to left, making it look backwards. I fixed it and I got this:

```
make: *** אך אין כללים לבנייתה ,`\Program' דורשת `g++' מטרה.  Stop.
```

Which Google Translate translates to:

```
make: *** but there are no rules for its construction, `\ Program requires that` g ++ 'goal. Stop.
```

To fix it, either:

- run `LANG=C LC_ALL=C make` instead of `make` to run the build process using POSIX English locale
- or change settings of your terminal emulator to use ISO-8859-8 – you can do it the standard Windows command prompt with `chcp 28598` command, but you'll also need an appropriate font